# Replicating a feature in multiple react components

Tags: reactjs, components

In my application there are four tabs. Each tab contains, different tables for different set of data. I have implemented a modal and search functionality on 1st tab. How to replicate it without much code repetition.

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable that allows you which tab to render. Use this variable to figure out which table to search on. The modal instead you have to keep it off the tabs so that you can reuse it properly (global position respect tabs)

Add Switch statement if you want handle the situation (based on this variable).

For the future, post code. We can help you with more ease and less time

Answer (score 1):

You have few options:

1. Create a component which will be the exact styles in all of the tables.
2. Create a component with className (or any other style) prop, which will look different inside each table.
3. Create customHook which will be used to search & filter, and use it's exported variables inside your component - here logic will be the same (and the same code), but styles and/or behavior will be different.